# How do I control only the "second oscillations" of a curve?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, graphing-functions, curves

I have the following "elastic out" curve:

$$f_b(t)=1+2^{-10t}\cdot \sin\left(\frac{(t-\frac{b}{4}) \cdot 2π}{b}\right)$$

I only need to use it in the interval $\left(0, 1\right)$ (values for $0$ and $1$ do not matter). It already describes the oscillation after "getting to" $y=1$ quite well, however, I am facing issues trying to design the dampening according to my needs and transforming this curve in general.

[image]

### Problem

Above you can see what $b$ controls - I would say the dampening of the oscillation but also not really. What I want to have control over ideally is only the dampening about $1$ after the function comes back to $y=1$ for the first time, so I want to keep the initial bump past $y=1$ from say $b=0.4$, but I want more overshoot past $y=1$ afterwards.

[image]

This is a terrible sketch, but I hope that you see what I mean. The red graph would be what I have now with $b=0.4$ and the blue graph is what I am trying to achieve.
I tried a bunch of edits to the equation, but nothing I did got me close to what I want. The graph should keep oscillating about $y=1$ after some time.

### Observations

Changing the factor before the $sin$ will obviously allow me to stretch and compress the whole graph, but that is not what I want.

### Application

The point of this curve is to describe motion from one place to another. An object is supposed to move from say $A$ to $B$. $A$ is at $y=0$ and $B$ is at $y=1$. $y=1.1$ would mean that the object moved past the destination (past $B$), which is why this is "elastic". My goal is to keep the intial elasticity of the bounce, i.e. the overshoot past $B$, but I also want to have more bounciness when the object oscillates about point $B$ after going beyond it initially.

Comment: I feel terrible saying this because obviously you've put lots of efforts in this question, but *I can't see what you mean*.

Comment: I guess it comes down to explain this sentence with more detail: *What I want to have control over ideally is only the dampening about 1 after the function comes back to =1 for the first time, so I want to keep the initial bump past =1 from say =0.4, but I want more overshoot past =1 afterwards.*

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Thanks for taking a look. Does the "Application' section I added help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly, you want an envelope function $g$ such that $g(0) = 0$, $g(x)\approx x$ for $x > 1$, but you want $g(x) < x$ in that range $(0, 1)$ so that $g(f_b(x))$ has lower troughs than you presently have.

If we were to use some sort of bell-shaped curve, say, a Gaussian $h(x) = e^{-x^2}$ then we could form such a function as $g(x) = x(1 - \alpha h(x/\beta)$ for two parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$ that tell us about the strength and the spreadiness of the envelope. Some more shaping can be done by using $(h(x/\beta)/h(0))^n$ or so instead of just $h(x/\beta)$ in there. So for example with $g(x) = x(1 - 0.8 e^{-6 x^6})$ I can get a graph like

[image]

(blue is original, black is after the envelope transformation).

The only weird thing about this sort of approach is the way it messes with the slope near $x=0$.

Comment: Thanks so much. About your interpretation of what I meant: $x>1$ does not matter ($g(x)\approx x$ is not needed) and yes, I want lower (lower $y$ value) troughs than I have with $f$. The black function you graphed actually looks exactly like what I wanted, however, I cannot seem to replicate it. I must be missing something. I tried to copy your $g$ with the parameters already filled in as $q$ and also tried figuring out what parameters you used, but my graphs look completely different. Can you take a look [at this image](https://imgur.com/berRuja)? It is probably something very basic.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot what grapher are you using?

Comment: As I said, I was being silly. I reckoned that I did not read your answer properly, so I came back to check and it  turns out that I did miss that you mentioned $g\left(f\left(x\right)\right)$. I also tried $f\left(g\left(x\right)\right)$ before finding my mistake, but that oviously does not yield the correct result. I have to say - sorry for misreading your answer multiple times - I assume that you noticed my mistake already, but could not be bothered to explain it to me.

Comment: Thank you again for your answer. I ended up with $x\left(1-4e^{-5x^{12}}/ 9\right)$ for my envelope translation.